# Sitecore Rich Text Editor removing 'autoplay' attribute

Tags: richtext-editor

I'm trying to embed a video in a Rich Text editor like so:

```
<div class="video-wrapper">
    <video autoplay loop poster="/img/hero-stills/Homepage.jpg" style="margin-top: -295px;position:absolute;left:20px;">
        <source src="/img/hero-videos/Homepage.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
        <source src="/img/hero-videos/Homepage.webm" type="video/webm"></source>
        <img src="/img/hero-stills/Homepage.jpg" alt="Three standing robots" />
    </video>
</div>
```

But when I save and close it, the `autoplay` and `loop` attributes get removed. How can I prevent these from getting removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is you can just use the true or false for those attributes you require to implement. Simply just doing `autoplay="true"  loop="true"  controls="true"`

Because `autoplay="true"` and `autoplay` is all same.

Check this. It works like a charm.

[image]

For reference check this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the attributes are removed is because [empty attributes are not valid in XHTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.5) and the RTE control in Sitecore is configured as XHTML by default (you will see the same behaviour on the [Telerik RadEditor demo page](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/builtincontentfilters/defaultcs.aspx)).

The simplest and no code solution solution is to fully specify the attributes such as `autoplay="true"` as suggested [in the answer by @Sam](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/11225/135).

### Disable XHTML

An alternative is to update the Sitecore Rich Text Editor to disable XHTML mode. You can see the behaviour in the Telerik demo page by unchecking the "ConvertToXhtml" option. I have previously blogged how to do this and you can [read more in my article](https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2016/02/09/sitecore-telerik-rte-settings/).

Create a new class to override the `SetupFilters()` method and disable the `ConvertToXhtml` filter:

```cs
public class RteConfiguration : Sitecore.Shell.Controls.RichTextEditor.EditorConfiguration
{
    public RteConfiguration(Item profile) : base(profile)
    {
    }

    protected override void SetupFilters()
    {
        base.SetupFilters();
        Editor.DisableFilter(EditorFilters.ConvertToXhtml);
    }
}
```

You will need to add a reference to `Sitecore.Kernel.dll` and `Telerik.Web.UI.dll`.

To use the new configuration, update the `HtmlEditor.DefaultConfigurationType` setting to your own class:

```xml
<settings>
  <setting name="HtmlEditor.DefaultConfigurationType">
    <patch:attribute name="value">MyProject.CMS.Custom.Controls.RteConfiguration, MyProject.CMS.Custom</patch:attribute>
  </setting>
</settings>
```

Certain `HTML Editor Profile` in the core database specify the `Configuration Type` directly (e.g. `/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Default`) then you either need to remove the item from the profile so it uses the `HtmlEditor.DefaultConfigurationType` setting or update the setting item to point to your class instead.

Now when you add the attributes they will not be removed, **but** it will update with an empty attribute value if you use the Rich Text Editor, e.g. `<video autoplay="" loop="" ... >`. Even with the empty values, it should be valid and behave as expected.

The `Edit Html` leaves the attributes alone and exactly as entered.

### Remove Validation Errors

You will also see validation errors on the field, which may also fail Workflow Validation if you have this enabled (this is the same for both answers, not just this specific solution):

[image: Field Validation Errors]

To disable these you can [remove the XHTML Validation Rules](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/941511) from Rich Text and Global Rules items:

- `/sitecore/system/Settings/Validation Rules/Field Types/Rich Text`
- `/sitecore/system/Settings/Validation Rules/Global Rules`